# jQuery UI datepicker allow select of 2 days from today

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I used jQuery UI datepicker for a calendar. I want to show today's date as highlighted but only allow users to pick dates that is 2 days from "today's date" Is there a way to do this?  I know I can use below code to make it blocked out as many days as I want but the problem with this solution is today's date become grayed out.  I want don't want it to be grayed out.

```
$j(function() {
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 3, maxDate: "+3M" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by overriding the css for ui-datepicker-today

```
td.ui-datepicker-today{
    font-weight:bold !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
    background-color:blue;

}

td.ui-datepicker-today span{
    background:blue !important;
    color:white !important;
}
```

In this way todays date will be highlighted but will not be enabled for selection.

You can change the css to the give to the look that you need.

Comment: Yes the plugin does not come with a feature to do this, so we have to make a custom override.